# Efficient search algorithm to find duplicate strings

Tags: c, algorithm, search, data-structures

Below is the algorithm to find a duplicate string pattern. All the strings already have been added in a linked list, now the job is to find a duplicate pattern.

String length can be 8-20 characters and the number of string elements in the linked list is between 100 and 200. The current approach seems to have complexity and efficiency issues. Can anybody suggest most efficient approach for this?

```
typedef struct Map
{
        int8_t *string;
        struct Map  *next;
}map_t;

//Algorithm to find the duplicate string pattern in link list.  

int16_t findDuplicateOids(map_t *head)
{
  map_t *ptr1, *ptr2;
  ptr1 = head;
  /* Pick elements one by one */
  while(ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL)
  {
     ptr2 = ptr1;
     /* Compare the picked element with rest of the elements */
     while(ptr2->next != NULL)
     {
       /* If pattern is similar than return return error */
       if(!strcmp(ptr1->string , ptr2->next->string))
       {  printf("match happened");
          return RESULT_ERROR;
       }
       else 
       {
          ptr2 = ptr2->next;
       }
     }
     ptr1 = ptr1->next;
  }
  return RESULT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What level of performance do you want to achieve? Naive algorithm looks fine for 100 strings.

Comment: do you mean to say this algorithm will be efficient for 100 strings?

Comment: It depends on how fast do you need it to be. What running time do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want improve the time complexity of your algorithm, you can:

1. Sort the strings in lexicographical order. Then you need to check only pairs of consecutive strings. This approach has `O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)` time complexity.
2. Use a hash table. This solution has `O(n)` time complexity in average case.
3. Use a trie. Again, `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. could you share implementation info regarding hash table implementation as never done this before.

Comment: @user2997518 Here is an article about hash table C implementation: http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)HashTables.html

Comment: I have decided to use insertion sort for sorting the strings in lexicographical order and after that  i am calling findDuplicateOids method . i believe this approach will have O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n) complexity. Thanks user2040251 for your valuable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can improve your complexity using following steps-

1. Use suffix array to sort the string in lexicographic order in complexity O(nlogn).
2. Compare adjacent strings.total number of comparsion reduced to n.So complexity of this step is O(n).

   So total complexity is O(nlogn) + O(n) = o(nlogn).